# Is there any windows equivalent of Original Linux Magic-SysRQ Key?

Tags: windows, operating-system

Is there any way to debug/gather some diagnostic information in case a windows machine hangs/freezes to get some clue about what caused the hang/freeze., just like linux has

[Magic_SysRq key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key)

Is there any way one can connect to a frozen/hanged windows to get some log having some memory info, process info, registers/flags status info from the OS.
Or some way to kill the process which could have caused the freeze. Basically try to give some restore command to saLvage the hanged situation?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

Closest thing I can think of is enabling RightCtrl+ScrollLock, which will bluescreen the machine (thus creating a memory dump).  This can be examined in WinDBG, with which you will be able to examine everything (threads, registers, memory, etc).

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/244139

Info about doing so with a USB keyboard (you need Vista/WS 2008 SP1 or later, plus this hotfix):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971284

Here are some troubleshooting steps in case it doesn't work:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927069

Here's more general info about creating a memory dump:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/972110 (WS 2003)

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969028 (WS 2008)

Comment: AFAIK Ctrl-ScrollLock should be enabled manually. It does nothing without registry modification

Answer (score 0):

You need to have windbg installed.